# Ng-options with order by duplicate values in IE and MS Edge

Tags: angularjs, list, duplicates, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with my application for Cordova windows.
My list duplicates first items using ng-options with order by.

I'm using angular 1.5.3 and meta widget in the HTML.

UPDATE:

I'm noticing something weird in Angular but only for IE 11 and edge. This doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox

I have a multi-select box

Because I have the group by clause, the first group of the options are doubled. There are some other weirdnesses with adding and removing values from model and having them not disappear from the select box as well.

[My app started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxeUH.png)

code is:

```
 motivoVisitaList: {                     
             col:'col-100 tablet-100',
             type:'array',
             componentType:'smartSelect',
             dataOpenIn:'page',              
             dataSearchbar:true,
             dataTextField:'nome',
             required: true,
             label:'"Motivo da visita"',
             options: 'motivo as motivo.nome group by motivo.grupo for motivo in motivos track by motivo.id',     
             midia:{
               icon : 'fa fa-lg fa-question-circle',
             },
```

values:

```
var motivos = [];                                

        motivos.push(new Motivo(1,'Cadastro ou atualização','Rotina'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(29,'Visita Periódica','Rotina'));

        motivos.push(new Motivo(2,'Consulta','Busca Ativa'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(3,'Exame','Busca Ativa'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(4,'Vacina','Busca Ativa'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(30,'Condicionalidades do Bolsa Familia','Busca Ativa'));

        motivos.push(new Motivo(5,'Gestante','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(6,'Puérpera','Acompanhamento'));            
        motivos.push(new Motivo(7,'Recém-Nascido','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(8,'Criança','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(9,'Pessoa com Desnutrição','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(10,'Pessoa em reabilitação ou com deficiência','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(11,'Pessoa com hipertensão','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(12,'Pessoa com diabetes','Acompanhamento'));            
        motivos.push(new Motivo(13,'Pessoa com asma','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(14,'Pessoa com DPOC / Enfisema','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(15,'Pessoa com câncer','Acompanhamento'));
        motivos.push(new Motivo(16,'Pessoa com outras doenças crônicas','Acompanhamento'));
```

.
.
.

Comment: What is the ***actual*** problem?

Comment: My list duplicate first item

Comment: Edits for legibility, although I can only take it so far.

Comment: i'm update the question